# Radius server failed to start in centos 7

Tags: apache, mariadb, centos7, freeradius

At beginning I successfully configured radius server with mariadb and httpd. But I changed to hostname of the server and rebooted. Now even if the mariadb and httpd is running but radiusd failed to start. Here is the answer from journalctl -xe .. Please help me.

```
Jan 10 12:34:08 cpe.twcny.res.rr.com systemd[1]: Unit radiusd.service entered failed state.
Jan 10 12:34:08 cpe.twcny.res.rr.com systemd[1]: radiusd.service failed.
Jan 10 12:34:08 cpe.twcny.res.rr.com polkitd[963]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2183:15540 (system bus name :1.43, object path /org/
Jan 10 12:40:01 cpe.twcny.res.rr.com systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
```

Comment: try running with ``radiusd -X``

Comment: Thank you for the advice but now it is solved. There was mistake in the database so it was not starting.